# Does iTunesConnect Use Nearest Translation?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

For example, if you add a Brazilian translation for your app description but not a Portuguese translation? Will Portugal see the Brazilian or English?

Comment: You could just try it out...

Comment: How do I access the localized iTunes pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Apple's documentation each regional store is associated with a primary and auxiliary languages.  e.g. UK English would be a supporting language in the USA store.

Likewise Brazilian and Portuguese dialects would be primary and supporting languages in their respective stores.